# Share Folders / Network Drives Server 2008

Tags: windows, networking, windows-server-2008, sharing, windows-server

I am using windows server 2008, where I want to give specific users separate share folder or mapped network drive which can be accessible by only the valid user, where they can secure their data as a backup.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: What have you tried for this so far? Please let us know what is the exact issue you are facing while doing this.

Comment: I created seperate folder for each user and share it and configure the security settings. But the problem is their is a long list of share folders appearing in network places. I want to group them in one folder.

Comment: What is your work till now.?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about file sharing, but it isn't worthy of migrating to another site.

Answer (score 0):

From your requirements I think it's safe to say you're looking to use the "home folder" feature of Windows Server, present since server 2003 there's multiple benefits and reasons for using it, listed below are a few:

- All users have a central server location for their data.
- Users are working on the network so can access their data from any machine *(on the network)*
- You can enable version control and server backups to the user home directory shares.

Read [this MSDN article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816313), it's very easy to implement and it sounds like what you're looking for.

Also the wildcard `%username%` means you can set a share for example `//server//users//%username%` in your ADUC, I often create a default user per container for example _default and copy that user when creating new users, (the _ ordering the user at the top of the list and the %username% automatically takes the firstname.surname of the user, this means you don't have to change the home folder on new users or for name changes)

Comment: Thanks, I think thats what I want

Comment: But Sam the problem is all the users whose share/home folder i created in active directory can access each others shared/home folders.

Comment: Yes, you have to manually configure the permissions initially. Give permissions to the creator of files (users) and to domain administrators.